# show activity only after layout loaded

Tags: android

I have a question, How can I show one activity after the layout has fully loaded.

For example: I have a listview , when I click on a item it loads a profile, tha profile has a view pager and loads images from the internet.

I want the listview stop to display just after thar layout has been fully loaded.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think the better way is to show a dialog when the listview start loading and dismissing when it finish... I'm using listview as well and is has to syncronize with the data of the server.
Basically do this..

`@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }`

`@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
     //do your stuff such as getting data from server.
}`

`@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //do your stuff such as setting data obtained before
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss()
        }`

Answer (score 0):

For example you can make the view pager invisible and set it visible when all images are loaded.